# Where clause from OUTER APPLY using LEFT function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

What would be a good alternative to improve my where clause that currently uses the LEFT function?

Should I create a persisted computed column and an index to it?

```
SELECT --columns--
FROM DesvioDesenhoSubstitutivoProposto DSP 
LEFT JOIN DesvioDesenhoSubstitutivo DS ON DS.idSubstituicaoDesenho = DSP.idSubstituicaoDesenho OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT TOP 1 D.Dendis
   FROM Interfaces.dbo.SSOLQ068 D
   WHERE DS.codigoDesenhoSubstitutivo = LEFT(D.NDISCOMPLFAB, LEN(D.NDISCOMPLFAB)-1)
   GROUP BY D.Dendis) AS DESEN
```

This is the current execution plan for this part:

[image]

PS: query has been simplified for posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
WHERE D.NDISCOMPLFAB LIKE DS.codigoDesenhoSubstitutivo + '_'
```

...which will allow an index on `(NDISCOMPLFAB, Dendis)` to be used effectively.

Please check that the column types are the same kind between `D.NDISCOMPLFAB` and `DS.codigoDesenhoSubstitutivo`, such as both nvarchar or both varchar. If they are different, use:

```
WHERE D.NDISCOMPLFAB LIKE CAST(DS.codigoDesenhoSubstitutivo AS ...) + '_'
```

...where the ... is whatever the type of `NDISCOMPLFAB` is.

Also, the `GROUP BY` clause should be redundant because of the `TOP 1`.

Comment: Sorry I missed that one. Now it is: http://i.imgur.com/n7LWkFX.png and the plan has changed to http://i.imgur.com/XFzfPcU.png (estimate) and http://i.imgur.com/gXUvFNr.png (actual) using LIKE. Now it is executed in less than 1 second. Thank you.